# Does the fully distributed wso2 cep deployment varies for 4.2.0

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I have setup a wso2 cep cluster based on https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Fully+Distributed+Deployment for 4.0.0 
What extra do i need to do to upgrade to 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

There's no huge difference between SP400 and SP420 (with respect to distributed setup). So, please refer to the following documentation[1] on upgrading WSO2 stream processor.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP4xx/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release.

Comment: Please refer to official doc on 420 space : https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP420/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release